# How to show marker again when I was used map.clear()

Tags: swift, google-maps

I am new in Swift and my english is not very well

I used  this function to control `marker` show up or disappear

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position:GMSCameraPosition) {


        if mapView.camera.zoom < 10 {
            print("zoom < 10")                
            mapView.clear()
            }
        if mapView.camera.zoom > 10 {
            print("zoom > 10")
            GMSMarker().map = mapView
            }
}
```

when `zoom < 10` the markers is disappear

but when I zoom in let `zoom > 10`. the markers doesn’t show up at mapview again

someone can tell me what should I do?

I'll be grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
mapView.clear()
```

clears all markers on the map , and this

```
GMSMarker().map = mapView
```

creates a new 1 on the fly with no properties , you need to keep your markers in an array then if you want them to re-appear again after you call `clear` do

```
allMarkers.forEach { $0.map = mapView }
```

where

```
var allMarkers = [GMSMarker]()
```

Comment: sorry I don't get that. I put `var allMarkers = [GMSMarker]()` and `allMarkers.forEach { $0.map = mapView }` in `if mapView.camera.zoom > 10 { }` but it's don't work. Am I wrong?

Comment: every marker you added previously to the map should be added also to  `allMarkers` array